# How to create C# classes from multiple XML files automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-parsing, visual-studio-2022

I know I can go "Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as classes", but I have 128 XML files so I really don't want to manually repeat this procedure 128 times. How can I do it all automatically?

Comment: Look up the XSD.exe command line tool.  It may do what you want (if not directly, in a simple batch file).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-def-tool-gen

Comment: By the way, if it does, write it up as an answer and accept it

Comment: Or put them all in one file and paste that. Or use a AutoHotKey script

Comment: Save it in the folder, and then use the script to traverse all the xml files in the folder.